# Add places API data in RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-places-api, android-recyclerview

I am working on an android app that get places around the user and display it to him. I want to present the places to him on a `CardLayout` using the `RecyclerView` in a fragment. I tried to implement these but when I run the app on my device , it displays just a blank page while in the Logcat, it shows the names of places around me. I don't really know if my implementation of `viewadapter` is the problem..Please need help. Here is the fragment and `placesadapter` Class.

```
public class CardFragment extends Fragment implements GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "CardFragment";
    protected GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
    PlacesAdapter adapter = null;
    RecyclerView lstPlaces;
    private ArrayList<Place> place = new ArrayList<>();
    public CardFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // addPlaces();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getContext())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(Places.PLACE_DETECTION_API)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        adapter = new PlacesAdapter(place);
        retrievePlaces();

    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.card_fragment, container, false);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        lstPlaces = (RecyclerView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.list_places_recyclerview);

        lstPlaces.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        lstPlaces.setAdapter(adapter);
        return rootView;

    }
    // Handle the result from requested permissions.
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[],@NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if ((grantResults.length > 0) && (grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                    Log.i("Permision", "permission granted");
                }
                break;
        }
    }
    //Handle onConnectionFailed
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" + connectionResult.getErrorCode(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    private void retrievePlaces() throws SecurityException {

        PendingResult<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer> result = Places.PlaceDetectionApi.getCurrentPlace(mGoogleApiClient, null);
        result.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<PlaceLikelihoodBuffer>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {

                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                    place.add(placeLikelihood.getPlace());
                    Log.i("Place = ",  placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName().toString());
                }

                likelyPlaces.release();
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

            int hasPermission = 0;

            hasPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
            if (hasPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(), new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
            } else {
                Log.i("Client Connection", "Connected to GoogleClient");
            }


    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }


}
```

PlaceAdapter

```
public class PlacesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter <PlacesAdapter.PlaceViewHolder>{

    private ArrayList<Place> places = new ArrayList<>() ;

    public PlacesAdapter(ArrayList<Place> places){
        this.places = places;
    }


    @Override
    public PlaceViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
        return new PlaceViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(PlaceViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.placeName.setText(places.get(position).getName().toString());
        holder.telephone.setText(places.get(position).getPhoneNumber().toString());
        holder.adress.setText(places.get(position).getAddress().toString());
        holder.location.setText(places.get(position).getLocale().getDisplayName());
        holder.website.setText((CharSequence) places.get(position).getWebsiteUri().toString());
        //holder.placeName.setText( places.get(position).getTelephone());
    }
    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return places.size();// places.size();
    }

    public static class PlaceViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView placeName;
        TextView telephone;
        TextView adress;
        TextView location;
        TextView website;
        CardView cardView;


        public PlaceViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
            placeName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.place_name);
            telephone = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.telephone);
            adress = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.adress);
            location = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.location);
            website = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.website);
        }
    }
}
`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in onResult() method as @Cong Nguyen said, I found out that I had to call freeze() method on the Place object before releasing the buffer as written in documentation https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/buffers .
onResult method now is like this. Thanks

```
' public void onResult(@NonNull PlaceLikelihoodBuffer likelyPlaces) {

                for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
                    place.add(placeLikelihood.getPlace().freeze());

                    Log.i("Place = ",  placeLikelihood.getPlace().getName().toString());
                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                likelyPlaces.release();
            }'
```

Answer (score 0):

It's null because you added an item to the list after you call `setAdapter()` method. So, you must call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` after you add an item to the list (in onResult() method).

Comment: I called adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() in onResult() method but it didn't work.Places are shown in logcat but the app crashes. http://imgur.com/U5LeFg9